# Mount a NFS partition from a NAS server

Tags: nfs, nas

We have a NAS server in the lab and I can reach it through the web interface at `192.168.1.100`, and I have enabled NFS on the admin's panel.

[image]

After that I did

```
sudo aptitude install nfs-common
sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.2.254:/gwas_data /media/thecus
```

Result:

```
mount.nfs4: Connection timed out
```

OS is Ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried replacing the IP address with your NAS's actual IP?

Comment: Possibly your firewall blocks the ports necessary for NFS (and maybe also rpcbind). Have a look at `dmesg | tail` right after trying the mount command.

Comment: thecus OS5 or 6- slight changes to os7. hope it helps.

Comment: Also check the NFS version supported by the NAS. Sometimes they don't do NFSv4 so you may need to enable NFSv3 support client-side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **public** folder (FMBData in this example)
2. Click on NFS to share it
3. Set the hostname to the IP of the linux machine (e.g. 192.168.1.111)
4. On the linux machine, `sudo apt-get install nfs-common`, `sudo mkdir /media/thecus`,  then `sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.100:FMBData /media/thecus`. You can get the WAN IP of the server on the front screen.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could detail which NAS this is for - there are several brands and firmware revisions and thiis question and answer is very specific.